# How to add my custom view to XML layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, custom-controls

I wrote the following view:

```
public class EllipseView extends View {

private final Paint paint = new Paint();


public EllipseView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawOval(new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()), paint);
}
}
```

How to add it to layout in XML? The following does not work (debugger does not connect):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<View class="com.incubation.EllipseView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ADDON**

There were also a problem with communicating with Eclipse and Device, which required restart to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<com.incubation.EllipseView
    android...
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<com.incubation.EllipseView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
/>
```